# Ensuring my function inside of a library is called with in range parameters

Tags: javascript, shared-libraries, default

I've written a function that accepts an object as the parameter. Said object contains various additional parameters. This works like many jQuery functions.

What is the best way to ensure that the object contains the required minimal parameters and how can I assign defaults to those parameters that are not required?

Here is what I am doing now.

```js
/*
 var options = {
  ListTitle: "",
  WebPartID: "",
  DisplayField: "Title",
  EnforceUnique: true,
  AllowEmpty: true,
  RequireSelection: true,
  NoSelectionMessage: "Please Select a Value",
  ConnectedWebPartID: ""
 }
 */

 //Set Defaults.
 dropdownFilterOptions.DisplayField = (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.DisplayField === "undefined" ? "Title" : dropdownFilterOptions.DisplayField);
 dropdownFilterOptions.EnforceUnique = (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.EnforceUnique === "undefined" ? true : dropdownFilterOptions.EnforceUnique);
 dropdownFilterOptions.AllowEmpty = (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.AllowEmpty === "undefined" ? true : dropdownFilterOptions.AllowEmpty);
 dropdownFilterOptions.RequireSelection = (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.RequireSelection === "undefined" ? true : dropdownFilterOptions.RequireSelection);
 dropdownFilterOptions.NoSelectionMessage = (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.NoSelectionMessage === "undefined" ? "Please select a value." : dropdownFilterOptions.NoSelectionMessage);

 //Parameter Validation.
 var parameterValidationSuccess = true;
 if (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.ConnectedWebPartID === "undefined") {
  throw "ConnectedWebPartID is required!";
  parameterValidationSuccess = false;
 }
 if (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.ListTitle === "undefined") {
  throw "ListTitle is required.";
  parameterValidationSuccess = false;
 }
 if (typeof dropdownFilterOptions.WebPartID === "undefined") {
  throw "WebPartID is required.";
  parameterValidationSuccess = false;
 }
 if (!parameterValidationSuccess) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no shortcut to check for required object properties (it has to be done one by one). If someone knows better, correct me!

For assigning something to the not required parameters, Object.assign() is a good choice:

```
// parameterObject is passed into the function
// parameterObject === { prop1: "Peter", prop3: "yep", prop4: 500 }
var defaultObject = { prop1: "default value 1", prop2: "default value 2" };
var finalObject = Object.assign(defaultObject, parameterObject);
// finalObject === { prop1: "Peter", prop2: "default value 2", prop3: "yep", prop4: 500 }
```

Above the parameterObject, that is passed into the function, is assigned into the defaultObject. This overrides all the defaultObject's properties that may be found from parameterObject but leaves untouched the ones that are only part of defaultObject.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Thank you! I will defiantly be using Object.Assign to assign defaults, but I will still look for a better way to check for required parameters.